# Excel COM add-in not loading in

Tags: excel, office365, add-in, comaddin

I have an excel com add-in. When I start excel drop this error message, and not load in the add-in:

The common language runtime could not be loaded by file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Obnex Technologies\SQL Spreads Desktop\SQL Spreads.vsto|vstolocal. Contact your administrator for further assistance.

In the background, the apllication drop this exception: Exception Code: 0xe06d7363, Parameters: , 0x19930520, 0x9ecfce90, 0x773e1258, 0x77390000

I have this office versions: Microsoft® Excel® a Microsoft 365-höz MSO (2307 buildverzió16.0.16626.20170) 64 bites

Please help me solved this problem.

Thanks the help.

I try to use an excel add-in...

Sorry, but I can't add comment now...So the answer: It's a good question. During the installation I had to choose whether I wanted to install the 64-bit or 32-bit version and I chose the 64. So I don't know why it goes there.

Comment: It would appear that you have a 32bit add-in but 64 bit Office. You need a 64bit version of the add-in if such a thing exists.

Comment: I have 64 office, and 64 bit add-in.

Comment: If it's a 64bit add-in, why is it installed in Program Files (x86)? That's where 32 bit programs go.

Comment: i don't know. The installation process ask the version and I chose the 64-bit version.

Comment: Then you may need to check with the developer